# Calculating displacement in three-weight pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I have a pulley system as shown in the below diagram with three attached weights: $A$, $B$, and $C$, with the rope connecting $A$ and $B$ making an angle $θ$ with the horizontal, and the rope connecting $B$ and $C$ making an angle $φ$ with the horizontal. If $B$ moves upwards by an amount $y$, how can I determine the corresponding motion of $A$ and $C$ in terms of $y$ and the angles $θ$ and $φ$?

[image]

My first instinct was to use trigonometry and say that the the vertical movement in $y = H_1 \sin θ$ where $H_1$ is the displacement in the direction of the rope between $A$ and $B$ and conversely $y = H_2 \sinφ$ where $H_2$ is the displacement in the direction of the rope between $B$ and $C$. The problem with this is that I expect the angles $θ$ and $φ$ to change as $B$ moves, whereas my attempt assumed them to be constant.

Comment: The tension in rope A is the weight of A while the tension in rope C is the weight of C. These components (relative to the two angles) of tension A and tension C must sum In X and Y to hold weight B in stasis.

Comment: This may help:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/649283/the-component-of-velocity-method-for-constraint-motion (not the same question though)